# Possible to position Jquery ui dialog box not relative to the viewport

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I try to position dialog boxes of Jquery ui with strict locations on website. I try to use them as little pop ups, goes around for a sec then repop them up at different location. However when I scroll my page, dialog boxes follow my viewport. I used this code to position them:

```
$("#bubble").dialog("option", "position", [xLoc,yLoc]);
```

Is there any way to give them strict locations?

Here you can check my website that I try on it. When you scroll down popups follow you :(

Comment: Can you provide a live example?  When I try this the dialog doesn't follow the viewport when I scroll - http://jsfiddle.net/AE9jY/.

Comment: It does not follow dynamically. It sets position for next pop up respected to your viewpoint. If you scroll down it starts to be poped up on your viewpoint but it need to be poped up on the top of the page so you could not see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [jQuery UI Dialog's docs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#option-position) the position option displays the dialog relative to the user's viewport.

Therefore if you don't want this functionality you should just re-position the dialog by altering the value of its `top` and `left` CSS values.  This will position the dialog in the top left corner of the screen regardless of the viewport.

```
$('.ui-dialog').css({
    top: 0,
    left: 0
});
```

Comment: Sorry but it does not work. Still same problem... :( although I put your code in $.ready

Comment: I solve my problem by using that code instead:

    $("#"+div).dialog("option", "position", [xLoc-window.pageXOffset,yLoc-window.pageYOffset]);

Answer (score 1):

```
$('your_selector').dialog({
  open: function(){
    $('.ui-dialog').css({
        "position": "absolute",
        "top": ( $(window).height() - $(this).height() ) / 2+$(window).scrollTop() + "px",
        "left": ( $(window).width() - $(this).width() ) / 2+$(window).scrollLeft() + "px"
    });
  }
});
```

i know it was somewhere added in some post, sorry for re-adding, but this should work